# How to return empty response with Varnish?

Tags: security, nginx, varnish

When a request come on a **Varnish** server, I would like to return an empty response or simply close the connection, if the requested server name is not known.

For example from nginx (the backend side of Varnish) I did that:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 444;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my.example.org
}
```

So, when an user/robot come on this nginx server with an address IP or an unknown host, it got: `The connection was reset`.

How do I?

---

With this configuration on **nginx** side and nothing more on **Varnish** side, if I try to access to the Varnish server with his public IP, I have: `Error 503 Backend fetch failed - Backend fetch failed - Guru Meditation`.

Perhaps there is a possibility on Varnish side, when response from backend (nginx) is 444, to simply close the connexion.

varnishlog says:

```
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
...
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 1540833
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   BackendOpen    33 default X.X.X.X 80 X.X.X.X 34862
...
-   FetchError     HTC eof (-1)
-   BackendClose   33 default
...
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   503
-   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
-   BerespHeader   Date: Fri, 10 Feb 2023 10:10:48 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
```

I want to "process" this error.

Answer (score 1):

If Varnish is hosted on the same machine as your Nginx server, Varnish should be listening on port `80` and Nginx on port `8080`.

Once Varnish can reach Nginx, the `Backend fetch failed` issue will go away.

In Varnish you don't need to configure anything special, whatever Nginx returns, Varnish will handle. However, if you want to handle this in Varnish before Nginx is reached, you could use the following VCL code:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if(req.http.Host != "my.example.org") {
        return(synth(403));
    }
}
```

This assumes that `my.example.org` is the right `Host` header. This also assumes that returning a synthetic `403 Forbidden` is an acceptable return value.

Comment: It's brilliant! It's working.

Comment: I updated my question. Your solution is working, but we are using this Varnish server with multiple hosts, and the system that apply the VCL don't know the list of hosts.  Is it possible to catch `FetchError HTC eof (-1)` to do something (for example to return an empty body)?

Comment: `FetchError HTC eof (-1)` is returned when the backend closes the connection. Please catch this one in `vcl_backend_error` if possible. See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#12-vcl_backend_error for the built-in VCL. You can use `beresp.status` and `beresp.reason` to catch the error and `bereq.http.Host` to match the host.